# How is the setup of a program created?

Tags: c#, installation

I want to create a setup for my own program. Is it possible to create the setup for any program including the window and gui based program? I want to know how the setup of a program is created in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Setup And Deployment project in Visual Studio](http://aspalliance.com/622_StepbyStep_Process_of_Creating_a_Setup_and_Deployment_Project.all).

Answer (score 0):

All a setup utility fundamentally does is copy files to some location.

That is not say that this is **all** they do. Most setup utilities will do much more besides, including:

- registering COM components;
- registering assemblies in the GAC;
- writing registry keys;

and so on. The Setup and Deployment project in visual studio is one solution. Another is [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which uses xml configuration files to produce an .msi installer, and [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which produces an .exe executable setup.

Can you give any more details about your requirements?